# Why doesn't this active pattern usage compile?

Tags: f#

**Why doesn't this active pattern usage compile?**

I receive an error on the following:

```
match cell1 cell2 with
| CellsAreDifferent -> isValueNeighbor cell1.X cell2.X
                    && isValueNeighbor cell1.Y cell2.Y
| CellsAreSame      -> false
```

> Type mismatch. Expecting a
>       Cell -> Choice<'a,'b>     but given a
>       Cell -> Cell -> Choice     The type 'Choice<'a,'b>' does not match the type 'Cell -> Choice'

**The code is here:**

```
let (|CellsAreSame|CellsAreDifferent|) cell1 cell2 =
        match cell1.X <> cell2.X
          ||  cell1.Y <> cell2.Y with
        | true  -> CellsAreDifferent
        | false -> CellsAreSame

let isNeighbor cell1 cell2 =

    let isAbsNeighbor v1 v2 =
        match abs (v1 - v2) with
        | 0 | 1 -> true
        | _     -> false

    let isValueNeighbor v1 v2 =
        match v1 >= 0
          &&  v2 >= 0 with
        | true  -> isAbsNeighbor v1 v2
        | _     -> isAbsNeighbor v2 v1

    match cell1 cell2 with
    | CellsAreDifferent -> isValueNeighbor cell1.X cell2.X
                        && isValueNeighbor cell1.Y cell2.Y
    | CellsAreSame      -> false
```

I was attempting to reference this [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233248.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you are trying to match on `cell1 cell2`.

This doesn't make sense as a value, as it is trying to use a value as a function.

I think the best solution would be to change to a tuple.

Something like

```
let (|CellsAreSame|CellsAreDifferent|) (cell1, cell2) =
```

and

```
match (cell1, cell2) with
```

Comment: So F# can only perform pattern matching on a single input?

Comment: Each pattern match takes in a single value. An active pattern takes in the single value to be matched on, but it can then also take further parameters (for partial active patterns only, I think).